# Does the Grbl have S-curve or harmonic velocity profiles?

Tags: control, servomotor, stepper-motor, cnc

I'm working on a machine and the position has a high impact by the jerk and acceleration of the machine. I'm using Grbl for my machine. Does Grbl has S-curve or Harmonic velocity profiles?

Answer (score 1):

grbl has a trapezoidal velocity profile. It has an acceleration limit (so a ramp on the velocity), but does not set a jerk limit. Jerk limiting would be probably an overkill for stepper-motors. However, grbl does use smooth stepping on for the stepper motors, this reduces the stepping frequency induced vibrations.

Source: [here](https://github.com/grbl/grbl/blob/3ce1a9d637f05e28462a36cb8b166386aab94afc/grbl/stepper.c#L142)